# Android application performance with soap

Tags: java, android, performance, web-services, soap

i am building a application for a takeaway resturant using SOAP as a webservice.

Problem:

1. When i try to open the application it loads every time. and if i have slow internet it will take some time which is not good for a professional application.
2. How can i cache the images in my mobile so it loads automatically

Possible Solution in my mind:

1. i think i should use the local database and sink it with internet
2. Use local cache system (but what if the application close).
3. Use arraylist to store information.

Can you guide me in that as i am stuck i do some reading but i don't feel any reliable solution on it.

Comment: 1)How can we know why your code is slow without seeing the code?  So I'm going to guess an evil wizard did it.  2)You save them to the filesystem so you don't need to download them a second time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some libs but you can lose images if the app is closed.
Actually you can cache images with libs and save them to sdcard at the same time. You need to save Their id in database. Then take data from sdcard by id from database in case you haven't internet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i am doing the same can you tell me any libray which i can use for cache and how i can reduce the server calls